# Umbraco Examine - how to sort search results?

Tags: search, sorting, lucene, umbraco

I am trying to sort my search results by a custom Umbraco property I have created - let's call it **sortDate**.

Inside my IndexSet, in `config/ExamineIndex.config` I have this:

```
<IndexUserFields>
        <add Name="sortDate" EnableSorting="true" Type="DateTime" />
        ...
```

In my Search user control, I am constructing a `criteria` and `filter` and using them to search like so:

```
var criteria =
      ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["MySearcher"].CreateSearchCriteria(
                UmbracoExamine.IndexTypes.Content);

var filter =
      criteria.GroupedOr(new string[] { "sortDate", "someThing", "someThingElse", "bodyText" }, SearchTerm.ToLower()).Compile();

var MySearchResults =
      ExamineManager.Instance.SearchProviderCollection["MySearcher"].Search(filter).Distinct();
```

I'm guessing I need to add something to specify how Lucene should sort this on my filter?

*This is Umbraco 4.6.1 if that matters :)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, not sure how I missed this, but it looks like you can just do:

```
filter.OrderBy( new string[] { "sortDate" } );
```

Comment: Thanks Elwyn, earlier one of the post suggested to use, _ or __ infront of name. But without any prefix I can see the results sorted as needed. Datetime value is converted to a numeric value for sorting i.e. 20121029134700 etc.

Comment: docs are here https://github.com/Shazwazza/Examine/wiki/Sorting-results